# android-KSOAP2 request call returns HTTP 500

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have seen all possible examples of how to use Ksoap2 with Android. I am able to access publicly available SOAP web services from the same code. But when I try to use my service team written SOAP services I am keep getting

"java.IO.exception: HTTP request failed: HTTPS Status: 500"
Basically call fails on HttpTransportSEObj.call(Namespace+methodname, envelope);

Same service I am able to call from iOS client.

I don't know what to do here.

Is is something to do with how namespace is different from my actual url? I don't know.

NameSpace: http://xyz.net/webmethod/mobile,
URL: http://xyz.com/lite/webmethod/mobile.asmx,
Method Name: Login

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit1:
I got more info from exception here is the response

soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Edit2 : Adding the calling code here

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("email","xyc.com");
    request.addProperty("password","Passw@rd1");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 


   envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    Log.i("bodyout", "" + envelope.bodyOut.toString());
    try {

           httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response

        if(result != null)
            Log.i("Response"," Service response is " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SOAP_TEST", "========= Request start =========");
        Log.e("SOAP_TEST", httpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.e("SOAP_TEST", "========== Request end ==========");
        Log.e("SOAP_TEST", "========= Response start ========");
        Log.e("SOAP_TEST", httpTransport.responseDump);
        Log.e("SOAP_TEST", "========== Response end =========");
        Log.e("", "error", e);
    }
```

}

Comment: Is this webservice .NET ?

Comment: did you set isDotNet flag true? Is it possible to show some code? It is hard to figure out like this.

Comment: Added response and calling code. Please have a look.